# How to traverse surface of sphere with two degrees of freedom?

Tags: lie-algebras, rotations

Is there a generic means of expressing the movement along the surface of a sphere with two degrees of freedom that doesn't have to deal with special cases?

For example, consider a unit sphere centered at the origin.  Most points can be rotated (moved along the sphere) by first rotating about the z axis (heading) followed by rotation about the y axis (pitch).  However, this has the special case that must be dwelt with -- the points at the poles that lie on the z axis.

(**edit**) To be specific, let's define movement along the sphere with two angles defined by these rotation matrices:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
-\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi & -\sin\phi & 0 \\
\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I try to rotate the vector $[0, 0, 1]^T$, $\phi$ does nothing and I can only move to points along the $xz$ plane.

Is there a more generic 2-DOF representation of the traversal of the surface of a sphere?

Comment: Polar coordinates?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "doesn't have to deal with special cases" the answer is no. Can you be more specific?

Comment: From the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), if we have a parametrization of the sphere $\vec r=f(u,v),\;\lVert\vec r\rVert=1$, then the tangent vector field $\partial\vec r/\partial u$ must vanish somewhere; at that point, changing the coordinate $u$ does not change the point $\vec r$ on the sphere.